# Cards in Bokeh Python application

Tags: python, bokeh, card

I am creating a Bokeh application in Python and was just wondering if there are any equivalence to **Shiny Dashboard Info Cards** for Bokeh applications / dashboards. I can see that there are cards from the dashboard example (top of the dashboard) on Bokeh site, https://bokeh.org/ [image]

but I can't seem to find the code for this anywhere. Any ideas on how to create cards using Python for Bokeh applications would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Panel.holoviz.org provides cards built on Bokeh...